# Bind a ViewModel to a DropDownListFor with a third value besides dataValueField/dataTextField

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I show a list of testplanViewModels in my View and the user selects one the SelectedTestplanId is returned to the Controller post action. What should also be returned is the TemplateId which belongs to the SelectedTestplanId.

When the AutoMapper definition is run the **Testplan.TestplanId** is implicitly copied over to the **TestplanViewModel.TestplanId**. The same could be done by providing a **TemplateId** on the TestplanViewModel. When the user selects now a "TestplanViewModel" in the View, how can I attach the TemplateId to the controller action to access it there? The DropDownList does not allow 2 dataValueFields!

```
CreateMap<Testplan, TestplanViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", src.Release.Name, src.Template.Name, src.CreatedAt, src.CreatedBy)));

public ActionResult OpenTestplanViewModels()
{
    IEnumerable<Testplan> testplans = _testplanDataProvider.GetTestplans();          
    var viewModel = new OpenTestplanViewModel
    {
        DisplayList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Testplan>, IEnumerable<TestplanViewModel>>(testplans)
    };
    return PartialView(viewModel);
}


public class TestplanViewModel
{      
    public int TestplanId { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }           
}


public class OpenTestplanViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No item selected.")]
    public int SelectedTestplanId { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<TestplanViewModel> DisplayList { get; set; }       
}
```

**OpenTestplanViewModel**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Open", "Testplan"))
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)      
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTestplanId, new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "TestplanId", "Name"), new { @class = "listviewmodel" })  
}
```

**Solution**:

```
 public class OpenTestplanViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "No item selected.")]
        public string TestplanIdAndTemplateId { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<TestplanViewModel> DisplayList { get; set; }

        public int SelectedTestplanId
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(TestplanIdAndTemplateId.Split(new[] { '_' }).First());
            }
        }
        public int SelectedTemplateId
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(TestplanIdAndTemplateId.Split(new[] { '_' }).Last());
            }
        }   
    }

 CreateMap<Testplan, TestplanViewModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(src =>  string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", src.Release.Name, src.Template.Name, src.CreatedAt, src.CreatedBy)))
                .ForMember(d => d.TestplanIdAndTemplateId, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.TestplanId + "_" + src.TemplateId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML doesn't really work that way. If you want more than one value returned from the post for the dropdown (the helper generates a `select` element), you'll have to create a property on your view model that you then parse within the controller.

For instance, if you had two integer `ID` fields, the combined property could create a value that looks something like `23_42`. You could then use the `Split` method to get the correct values (`23` & `42`) back.

Comment: ok I did it that way and it works. See updated code. But I am thinking about wether this logic belongs in the viewmodel OR creating a custom model binder OR in AutoMapper. Will do this in a new question.